# URL Rewrite Rule not working .htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I am trying to Rewrite the URL using .htaccess file but it is not working. First I tried a lot on my localhost and then on my Live Server but it's not working.. I still get the **original url**.That is what I have..

**Original URL:-**

http://test.1click.com.pk/specific_hall.php?hall_name=Shalimar+Hall&hall_id=1

**I Want:-**

http://test.1click.com.pk/Shalimar+Hall.php

**My .htaccess file:-**

```
 <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine on
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
   RewriteRule ^([^/]*)\.php$ /specific_hall.php?hall_name=$1&hall_id=1 [L]
   </IfModule>
```

I am still getting the original URL.. Can anybody please point out that why rewrite rule is not working? I tried a lot with no success. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: You always want Shalimar-Hall.php or depends on hall_name value ?

Comment: Thanks for reply @Sunil Pachlangia. I want depends on hall_name value..

Comment: what happen when you use http://test.1click.com.pk/Shalimar+Hall.php url??

Comment: @sundar Bons its working when I write this  test.1click.com.pk/Shalimar+Hall.php but when I click on the link to get the specific Hall Value it shows the original Url..

Comment: thats what it will do. it how rewrite works

Comment: But I want that when any user click on any Hall it will show rewrite Url instead of typing rewrite url manually..

Comment: You have to use the new URL in your HTML output.

Comment: @Mike Anthony. But how i use new url in my html because i am generating this url based on hall_name and hall_id it's dynamic when user click on any hall_name it will dynamically show that hall_name and its info. Is it possible when user click on any Hall then new URL will display?? Thanks for your time and reply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to include `hall_id` param in your new url format in order to rewrite it back. Otherwise, *mod_rewrite* has no way to know it.

You can put this code in your root htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/specific_hall\.php\?hall_name=([^\s&]+)&hall_id=(\d+)\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %2-%1.php? [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(\d+)-([^/]+)\.php$ specific_hall.php?hall_name=$2&hall_id=$1 [L]
```

Example:

1. `http://example.com/specific_hall.php?hall_name=Shalimar+Hall&hall_id=1`
   will redirect to `http://example.com/1-Shalimar+Hall.php` (no need
   to change links in your files).
2. `http://example.com/1-Shalimar+Hall.php` will internally rewrite to (=
   display the same content as)
   `http://example.com/specific_hall.php?hall_name=Shalimar+Hall&hall_id=1`

Comment: Thanks @Justin Lurman. It Worked like a charm. Can you please update this .htaccess file to remove + sign between string.. e.g (Shalimar + Hall).. I want Shalimar Hall Or Shalimar-Hall. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: You're welcome. Yes it's possible. But could you tell me if `hall_name` can contain any dash `-` ? Because it would be a problem if `Shalimar+Hall` becomes `Shalimar-Hall` and you have "native" dashes in others. Example: if `hall_name` is `Something-special` it would then become `Something+special` (which is not correct). Actually, you must ensure that the character you choose is not initially in all other `hall_name` possible values

Comment: Yes. @justin Lurman `hall_name` can contain dash `-`... Thanks for your reply and time...

Comment: Then it's up to you to choose a special character that would never be in `hall_name` (or you can keep `+` since it's not a problem for referencing and seo)